# Categorical feature relationship with target

Tags: correlation

When I'm working on dataset and want to explore different relationships between features and target, I often use visualization, only for regression with continous feature and continous target I use pearson correlation. And my question is how can I "measure" (if that's the right word) relationships for:

- Categorical to continous (usually I calculate mean for each group)
- Categorical to categorical (usually I explore distribution of feature classes in target classes)

What I'm asking is, what are ways to determine if variables which both are not continous, can be tested if they influance each other, influance that can be used for predictions

Comment: For categorical-to-categorical, use chi-squared. Otherwise, see this [Cross-Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102778/correlations-between-continuous-and-categorical-nominal-variables) answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a contingency table chi-squared test.

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as stats
contingency_table = pd.crosstab(df['categorical'], df['y'])
chi2_result = stats.chi2_contingency(contingency_table)
```